# DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR with filter on length(CLOB) results in ORA-06502

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

How can this raise an error?

```
select 
   DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR("CLOB-Data-Column",4000,1) as column_name 
from "Table_name"
where LENGTH("CLOB-Data-Column") <= 4000
```

the error is

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

There is no error when I try

```
select 
   SUBSTR("CLOB-Data-Column",1, 4000) as column_name 
from "Table_name"
where LENGTH("CLOB-Data-Column") <= 4000
```

but this is much too slow.

Acording to older questions on similar topic on SO and reference on Oracle documentation a string-length of 4000 should be fine for DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(). The number 4000 means the number of characters for CLOB (according to Oracle refrence). If I change the length of the filter something below 2000 the query would run without errors.

The database column is of the type CLOB. Oracle documentation says for 'amount' (the first argument of DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR): Number of bytes (for BLOBs) or characters (for CLOBs) to be read.

Comment: Experiment with `LENGTHB()` in the `WHERE` clause - that will give length in bytes.

Comment: lengthb("clob") is not allowed. Or did I get this wrong?

Comment: Ha, ha. I just checked the documentation, and you are *almost* right. `LENGTHB()` can be used with `LOB`, but only with single-byte ones. So, as applied to `CLOB`, it is completely useless; it can be used on a single-byte `CLOB`, but then it's the same as `LENGTH()`.

Comment: It depends on the character-set: With lenthb on my clob I get an error: ORA-22998: CLOB or NCLOB in multibyte character set not supported

Comment: Right: LENGTHB works only on single-character CLOBs (in which case, obviously, it's the same as LENGTH). According to AskTOM, there is no function in Oracle to give you the length IN BYTES of a CLOB in a multi-byte character set. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9526465800346614914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that some characters are **multi byte** ones. DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR counts characters, and these won't fit into a maximum allowed size of VARCHAR2 which is 4000.

Comment: According to documentation DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR() counts characters as well as length(). A single multibyte character counts as one character, right?

Comment: @Christian4145 - The problem, as you found out, is that DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR counts 4000 characters. If you have multi-byte characters, that will be a problem, because the function returns a VARCHAR2. If you use 4-byte characters, experiment with 1000 instead of 4000 everywhere. I doubt that DMBS_LOB.SUBSTR will be faster than SUBSTR (but it may be, depending also on your Oracle version).

Comment: DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR counts characters on CLOB but accepts only 4000 Bytes because of the returning datatype). On multibyte charactersets length() would count the number of characters what is not apropriate and lengthb() is not allowed. So setting the filter down to half (or quarter depending on characterset) of the size of DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR is the only way to do the job. I think you solved the problem!